# build.gradle: commandLine task failed due to "No such file or directory"

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

**tl;dr**
Problem: On my Mac using Android Studio, running a bash script task in gradle failed due to "No such file or directory" error even though the file is there.

**Background**:
I'm building an Android app using Android Studio on my Mac, and the app needs to build a C SDK which I use NDK with CMake for that. In my APP_FOLDER/app/build.gradle, I'm trying to run a script before building the CMake for NDK. This is the desired build order:

```
app:runBuildScript
app:configureCMakeDebug
app:externalNativeBuildDebug
app:compileDebugSources
...
```

The reason to run the script before CMake is because the script would set up a value that the CMake would use.

Here's my app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sdk"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
            }
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.21.3'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

task runBuildScript(type: Exec) {
    // commandLine 'source ./src/main/cpp/build-tools/bin/set-env.sh'
    workingDir './src/main/cpp/build-tools/bin'
    commandLine 'source ./set-env.sh'

}

project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName("buildCMakeDebug").dependsOn runBuildScript
}
```

**Problem**:
The script cannot run due to errors. Here's the error I received when building from Android Studio:

```
> Task :app:runBuildScript FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:runBuildScript'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'source ./set-env.sh''

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:runBuildScript'.
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "source ./set-env.sh" (in directory "/Users/xxxxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/SDKDemo/app/src/main/cpp/build-tools/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

However, the file is at location:

```
88665a32ce18:bin XXXXX$ pwd
/Users/XXXXX/AndroidStudioProjects/SDKDemo/app/src/main/cpp/build-tools/bin
88665a32ce18:bin XXXXX$ ls
build-tools.sh  set-env.sh
```

Any idea why it happens? Not sure if it's related, but the default shell on my Mac is zsh. Been stuck on this for a couple days and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why it's happening, but I come up with a workaround:

1. create a new .sh file(`source-settings.sh`) whose sole mission is to execute `source ./set-env.sh`.
2. changed `commandLine 'source ./set-env.sh'` to `commandLine "bash", "-c", './source-settings.sh'`